# removing numbers which are close to each other in a list

Tags: python, loops

I have a list like

```
mylist = [75,75,76,77,78,79,154,155,154,156,260,262,263,550,551,551,552]
```

i need to remove numbers are close to each other by maxumim four number like:

```
num-4 <= x <= num +4
```

the list i need at the end should be like :

```
list = [75,154,260,550]
```

or

```
list = [76,156,263,551]
```

doesn't really matter which number to stay in the list , only one of those which are close.

i tried this which gave me :

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if i==j or i==j+1 or i==j+2 or i == j+3:
            pp= l.pop(j)
            print(pp)
print(l)


IndexError: pop index out of range
```

and this one which doesn't work the way i need:

```
    for q in li:
        for w in li:
            print(q,'////',w)
            if q == w or q ==w+1 or q==w+2 or q==w+3:
                rem = li.remove(w)
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The below uses [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to identify runs from the iterable that start with a value `start` and contain values that differ from `start` by no more than 4.  We then collect all of those `start` values into a list.

```
from itertools import groupby

def runs(difference=4):
    start = None
    def inner(n):
        nonlocal start
        if start is None:
            start = n
        elif abs(start-n) > difference:
            start = n
        return start
    return inner

print([next(g) for k, g in groupby(mylist, runs())])
# [75, 154, 260, 550]
```

This assumes that the input data is already sorted.  If it's not, you'll have to sort it: `groupby(sorted(mylist), runs())`.

Comment: For this to work, `mylist` would have to be in a `sorted()` order, correct? Someday I wish I could get to the point of causally busting out standard libraries like that instead of slaving away with my own functions only to realize it already exists :\

Comment: @Idlehands That's correct (and an oversight on my part).  I'll add a note to my answer.

Comment: thanks , works nice
i don't understand how this exactly works, can you please help to store the in a dict like every number that remain be the key and value be  the iteration that make the number? like this:
```{125:0, 160:1: 195:2 ....}```

Comment: @Stick The function in a function lets us "remember" the start of the current run.  This is because calling `runs` creates an `inner` function that will then be called for every item in `mylist`. Since `inner` has a `nonlocal start` line, it can modify the `start` value from `runs`, which will persist across calls to `inner`. As for the dict, would `{next(g): i for i, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(mylist, runs()))}` work?

Comment: that is good but make each of them a dict, is there any way to put them in one ?
now its like this :
```{257: 0}
{358: 1}
{}
{174: 3, 371: 3}
{72: 4, 126: 4, 499: 4}
{}
{447: 6}
{28: 7, 312: 7}```


i want :

```{257:0,358:1...}```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow.  Are you running this on multiple lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a set or list, you don't need a dict.

```
usedValues = set()
newList = []

for v in myList:
    if v not in usedValues:
        newList.append(v)

        for lv in range(v - 4, v + 5):
            usedValues.add(lv)

print(newList)
```

This method stores all values within 4 of every value you've seen so far.  When you look at a new value from myList, you only need to check if you've seen something in it's ballpark before by checking usedValues.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the solutions:

```
numbers = [75, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 154, 155, 154, 156, 260, 262, 263, 550, 551, 551, 552]
new_numbers = []

for i in numbers:
    if len(list(filter(lambda x: (abs(x - i) < 5), new_numbers))) == 0:
        new_numbers.append(i)

print(new_numbers)

#[75, 154, 260, 550]
```

In this method we add a value to the new dict via an if condition. In the if clause, we check the old numbers against the list of new numbers, and if there are no numbers close to each other, we write them into the new dict.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76129853/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).